# My App sometimes causes WindowServer high CPU on Mac 10.12

Tags: xcode, macos

I am developing an UI application on Mac. After running about 1 hour, the application seems to become stuck. At the same time, the WindowServer process is costing very high CPU, from 50%~100%.

I googled a lot, it seems very few questions and answers related self developed application with WindowServer.

Does anyone know how to find what's causing the WindowServer cost high CPU? Any instruments in Xcode can help?

Comment: The issue is common. It occurs on my M1 Pro MBP also.  https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253387850 seems bug of Mac OS.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issues in my MacBook(Monterey 12.6) by changing "Scaled" to "Default" in Displays Setting.

[Figure: Change "Scaled" setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rmnxh.png)

How to change the resolution of your display:
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202471

Related Discussion:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8087967?page=3